# External Login on Facebook with custom parameter for asp.netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, facebook-login

I'm using external login with Facebook on my project ASP.NET Core with Oauth2.

I would like to pass a custom parameter so that it returns back after callback.
Is there a way to do this?

My use case:

- first action accept a parameter from query string `public
  IActionResult Register( string parameter) { ... }`
- can't use ViewBag and i would not use cookies
- after callback i need the same parameter in input as string parameter in
  `public IActionResult ExternalLogin( string provider, string returnUrl = null, string parameter = null ) {...}`

Comment: Does register call Challenge?

Comment: i return Challenge( properties, provider ) on method ExternalLogin, before login on facebook.

Comment: In the challenge you can set the properties.ReturnUrl (which it should already be doing) and you can add your parameter to that value.